# making density plot of histogram from dynamic data in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 2d

I have a numpy 2D array where the number of rows is dynamic and are realizations of a process. The columns are of a fixed length, in this case 10. The (i,j) values are all between 0.0 and 1.0. I would like to make a density plot, or a 2d histogram (surf?) where the x-axis has the 10 points and the y-axis is between 0 and 1. The density of the (i,j) point is the number of times the corresponding value appears in the entire array.

For example, let's say I have the following array:

```
arr = np.zeros((164,10))
for j in range(164):
    arr[j,:] = np.array([np.random.random() for i in range(10)])
```

How can I get a density plot where the x-axis is between 0 and 9 and the y-axis is between 0.0 and 1.0 with the density corresponding to (i,j) value.

This kind of gets me there but not really

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(70, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('imshow: equidistant')
im = plt.imshow(arr, interpolation='nearest', origin='low',
            extent=[x[0], x[-1], 0.0, 1.0])
plt.colorbar()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Worth looking in to this: http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html

Comment: Maybe you can point me to where this would help with my specific problem?